# Getting all params with same key from URL

Tags: javascript, c#, html, http

I have this code :

```
string langs = request.Form["lcid"];
```

This gives me that string : `"en,fr,es"` in `langs`.

These 3 entries have the same key : `lcid`.

My question is : **can I have it directly in an array ?** With this access :

```
[0] = "en",
[1] = "fr",
[2] = "es"
```

Hope I am understandable... Thanks.

Comment: `var array = langs.Split(',')`? Then you can access them as `array[0]`, `array[1]` and `array[2]`.

Comment: It should make it ! Thanks !

Comment: @SonerGönül : And what about `string langs = request.Form["lcid"].split(',')` : will this change `langs` to an array ?

Comment: Yes, this method returns a `string[]`. By the way, it is `Split`, not `split`. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all. Have a nice day.